# Assuming $m_i \mid d$ for any $i$, prove that $m_1m_2 \ldots m_r \mid d.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

> Let $m_1, m_2, \ldots, m_r$ be positive integers such that $\gcd(m_i, m_j) = 1$ when $i \neq j.$ Assuming $m_i \mid d$ for any $i$, prove that $m_1m_2 \ldots m_r \mid d.$

Suppose $\forall i(m_i \mid d)$. Since $\gcd(m_i, m_{i + 1}) = 1,$ we have that $(m_im_{i + 1}) \mid d.$ Also because $\gcd(m_im_{i + 1}, m_{i + 2}) = 1,$ we can say that $(m_im_{i + 1})m_{i + 2} \mid d.$ We argue like that until we exhaust all $m_i$.

Would you agree with this argument?

Comment: Yes, but you have to note that you are implicitly using induction on $r.$

Comment: @ C.I.J, thanks for pointing that out. I didn't even realize that.

Comment: More generally:

$$a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_k\mid d\iff \text{lcm}(a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_k)\mid d$$